# blender running slow and lagging

Tags: performance

I installed blender and tried to run it but it was running very slow. I tried with integrated graphics but still no use. I tried to roll back my drivers but that option was unable. I tried to change to windowed mode in user preferences but still no effect. Someone please tell me what to do because i really want to learn blender.

my laptop configuration is 8 gb ram, i5 8th gen and nvidia 940MX.

Comment: Try to make sure your nvidia drivers are latest version, blender UI is totally drawn with OpenGL...

Comment: Please describe your issue clearly. How is it slow, the software load slowly or the models in the 3d view rotated slowly? Or you have your 3d view in rendered mode that's why it's slow? With nvida 940MX it should not be slow. Be sure to check in the preference panel >> System Tab >> Cycle compute Devices is CUDA and the nvidia card 940MX is showing up in the list. If not you may have to force disable your intergrated card .